# How to add to every object of array new property value?

Tags: angular

In ngFor i have this:

```
let orderTracking of orderTrackings
```

And on some places i display data from orderTrackings, but on one place i have dropdown list.

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="selectDestination" (click)="orderTracking.selectDestination = selectDestination">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let destination of destinationsTo" [value]="destination.code">{{destination.displayname}}</option>
</select>
```

What im trying to do is to add selected value in that specific object in array, because every of that objects might have different values from dropdown. So when i in my .ts file display orderTrackings array to have for example:

```
orderTracking[0].something = 'something'
orderTracking[0].selectDestination = 1

orderTracking[1].something = 'test'
orderTracking[1].selectDestination = 5
```

And so on. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this my setting the ngModel to `orderTracking.selectDestination`. Since `[(ngModel)]` is two way data binding everytime the user chooses a new option from the select, the `selectDestination` property of that particular `orderTracking` gets updated.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="orderTracking.selectDestination">
   ...
</select>
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmjyue?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) demoing this.